# runAction(_:completion:) does not show Animation correctly

Tags: xcode, swift, skaction

I would like to run two actions at the same time and after them another two actions at the same time. Basically I would like to have two groups of action and run them in sequence. I could not manage to group my actions so I used the runAction(_:completion:) function:

```
self.orangeQuestionmark.runAction(group, completion: {     
        })
        self.blueQuestionmark.runAction(group, completion: {
            bubbleArray[0].hidden = false
            pony.runAction(ponyMove)
        })
```

This works fine unless this call:

```
pony.runAction(ponyMove)
```

With this call I call the animation. See code:

```
let ponyMove = ponyClass.movingPony("ponyScene3Move1", secondImage: "ponyScene3Move2")


class Pony: SKSpriteNode {
func movingPony(firstImage: String, secondImage: String) ->SKAction{
        let movePony = SKAction.animateWithTextures([SKTexture(imageNamed: secondImage), SKTexture(imageNamed: firstImage)], timePerFrame: 0.4, resize: true, restore: false)
        moving.append(movePony)
        moving.append(SKAction.repeatAction(movePony, count: 6))
        let group = SKAction.group(moving)
        return group

    }
```

}

However when I run this function outside my runAction(_:completion:) call it works perfectly fine.

Does anyone know what my fault is?

Comment: What is the problem you get when it doesn't _work perfectly fine_

Comment: It works perfectly fine when I run the animation from the beginning. So outside of the runAction(_:completion:). The problem is that I don't want to run this animation from the beginning. I want to run the other few actions first. If I choose to run the animation afterwards it skips every second image.

Comment: MovingPony should return a sequence SKAction not a group SKAction (groups run all at the same time)